# SQL to search for string matches and compute a percentage

Tags: sql, oracle, compare, match, percentage

I have a basic Oracle database with two tables.  I need to create a query that will try match records unambiguously using a simple first_name/last_name/address check.
What I also need from this is what percentage of records from Table A, are in Table B.

So I have something very basic like this at the moment:

```
SELECT First_Name, Family_Name FROM table_b
MINUS
SELECT First_Name, Family_Name FROM table_a;
```

Can anyone advise best way to develop/ change this to achieve my desired output?
Thanks!

Comment: Could you give an example and a desired output? I'm not sure what the output should be of your matching of records.

Comment: The percentage of records on one table, that are also found in the other table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use a JOIN and average the number of matches to get a percentage;

```
SELECT 100*AVG(CASE WHEN table_b.First_Name IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) percent
FROM table_a 
LEFT JOIN table_b
  ON table_a.First_Name  = table_b.First_Name
 AND table_a.Family_Name = table_b.Family_Name
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5c9f7/3).

Note that if there are duplicates, the count may be off.

Comment: Great, thanks!  "if there are duplicates, the count may be off" is there a workaround? For example, a way to list duplicates and records that can't be resolved? (name matches, but addresses are dissimilar)